Friend from Indonesia banned from entering Singapore after being denied entry to Japan
My friend who is an Indonesian citizen has been recently banned from entering Singapore after being denied entry to Japan because she didn’t have the right visa at the time to enter Japan. It was an honest mistake because we had thought Indonesian passport holders did not need a visa to enter Japan, but it turns out this only applies to e-passport holders.
She was immediately deported to Singapore airport first for layover and then to Indonesia. During the layover, she was brought into their immigration office, signed some paperwork and then informed her that she is banned from entering Singapore. The document she was given didn’t give a clear reason why and for how long she is banned.
Does anyone have recommendations on how she can regain her entry back to Singapore? From now on, does she have to apply for a visa every time she wants to visit? Can the Singapore embassy at her home country help with appealing her denied entry? When we contacted ICA, we were told to submit Form 14 on their website but this requires a sponsor from Singapore which she does not have.

Not sure why the Singapore embassy in her home country would involve itself in appealing her denied entry. Sounds like she needs to get advice from a qualified immigration lawyer.

Hope the airline hasn't sued her for the fine they received from the Japanese government for letting her board the flight to Japan in the first place
